# Where is the source code for the Reactjs material-ui demo?

Tags: material-ui

I'm of course talkin' 'bout this demo:

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar

And I'm assuming that all of it is dogfooding the material-ui library.

Comment: I am still not finding the source code of the components. Did you find it? if Yes, please send the url

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's in the `doc` folder of the library itself:

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/master/docs

Comment: If you are interested in using that as a starting point for a project, I've refactored the docs site to be a template for starting your own: https://github.com/lmaccherone/material-ui-template